# Is it possible to have multiple different pm2 instances running at the same time?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am just wondering if I can seperate my pm2 instances. For example, let's say I have one ecosystem file that I start in one terminal, and then I go ahead and start another ecosystem file in another terminal. Both processes seem to merge and start outputting the same logs. Becomes real annoying real quick. Is there a way to have them seperate?

Answer (score 2):

PM2 uses the `.pm2` folder by default to place its logs and .pid file. PM2 uses the PM2_HOME environment variable to know where this folder is. I uncovered this when I was moving the folder to a larger drive and ended up with a new instance when I checked on the apps it was monitoring.  As stated in the docs about [running multiple PM2 instances](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/), you can run multiple PM2 instance simply by specifying a different folder for each:

```
PM2_HOME='.pm2' pm2 start echo.js --name="echo-node-1"
PM2_HOME='.pm3' pm2 start echo.js --name="echo-node-2"
```

Keep in mind that to run any PM2 commands, you'll have to prefix with the proper PM2_HOME:

```
PM2_HOME='.pm2' pm2 list
PM2_HOME='.pm3' pm2 list
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party on this one, but for anybody in the future:

The problem in this question is that the log files are merging and being outputted in both instances.

To resolve this, in each of your ecosystem files, you would need to add a different location/filename for your log files on each instance, using `error_file` and `out_file`

**Example:**

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'Process name',
            script: 'index.js',
            error_file: '/path/to/error/file.log',
            out_file: '/path/to/log/file.log',
            ...additionalProperties
        }
    ]
};
```

For more information please see the [PM2 Ecosystem Documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)